# Jquery Mobile URL Appending Problem

Tags: url, parameters, jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery Mobile Navigation Bars to do my navigation from page to page (or from tonight to detail in this case).

My base URL is: `http://192.168.1.104/mobile/tonight.html`

I'm trying to navigate from my base URL using the following code:

```
<a href='detail.html?id=slide&place=" + data.Places[i].id + "' data-transition='slide' class='ui-link-inherit'>" + data.Places[i].name + "</a>
```

But is taking me to http://192.168.1.104/mobile/tonight.html#detail.html?id=slide&place=3

When what I really want is:
http://192.168.1.104/mobile/detail.html?id=slide&place=3

However, when I try linking directly to the full URL in the code, like:

```
<a href='http://192.168.1.104/mobile/detail.html?id=slide&place=" + data.Places[i].id + "' data-transition='slide' class='ui-link-inherit'>" + data.Places[i].name + "</a>
```

It directs me to: http://192.168.1.104/mobile/tonight.html#http://192.168.1.104/mobile/detail.html?id=slide&place=3

How do I get around this?  Do I need to make the href tag call a javascript function that would handle the url?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you have a # in href=''#detail.html ?

Comment: Took it out, still same behavior (I think I was just trying something and forgot to remove it before).

Comment: could you post the full code (2/3 lines around) where you generate the link ?

Comment: <a href="detail.html?id=slide&amp;place=3" data-transition="slide" class="ui-link-inherit">Big 12</a> is generating the link...  I can go directly to my desired page, as I have referenced above, but when I try and go via this link, it appends the desired href to the end of my current url...

Comment: I have this problem too and I certainly hope in the next alpha release of jquery mobile they solve it!! Here is another link to someone making the same query on the jquery mobile forum and one of the replies was that it is a known bug. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/rel-external-no-transition-effect-without-wrong-url. I hope that they do solve this, because I have had to take transitions out and make my links external to get the correct url. :( Sucks!!

Answer (score 4):

jquery mobile loads your links with ajax and appends to an existing page. It's all in the documentation. 
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/pages/link-formats.html

If you want the link to be loaded traditionally add `rel="external"` to your a tag.

Also:

Read some jquery mobile documentation or look at examples, because you should want it to work the way it works now and make your app work with it.

Use double quotes in your html like `href="detail.html"`